# WebSockets en Android? (kotlin)

Tags: javascript, android, nodejs, kotlin

mi problema es que he estado intentando implementar la api de kotlin de WebSockets (url  aquí https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/org.w3c.dom/-web-socket/) pero no he podido, me dice que hay demasiados argumentos. Aquí mi code:

```
private fun sendToPc(args: string) {
    open class WebSocket {
        var ws = WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080")
        ws.ONOPEN = fun() {
            ws.send(args)
        }
    }
}
```

captura de pantalla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `WebSockets` es de la web, te conviene mas en este caso usar `sockets` y no websockets son mejores para propositos multiplataforma y multilenguaje.

Comment: Los usaré entonces, gracias. Es que para Node es muy simple usar WS, pero mejor usare socket.io.